# Python, 'IndexError: list index out of range' when parsing large arrays BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, large-data

I keep on getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Project.py", line 100, in <module>
    parseData(array)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Project.py", line 91, in parseData
    name2 = pageSoup.findAll('div', {'class': 'item-title'})[0].string
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The array being passed into the function holds a couple thousand URL's. When I tested with an array of a much shorter length in the hundreds it was functional, finishing with no problems. I'm not too sure to why it is not functional when a larger array is used as an input.

```
def parseData(urls):
    f = io.open('output.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    for url in urls:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        responseContent = response.read()
        pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(responseContent, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf-8")
        if 'https://example.com' in url:
            name = pageSoup.findAll('h3', {'class': 'tb-main-title'})[0].string
            price = pageSoup.findAll('em', {'class': 'tb-rmb-num'})[0].string
            link = url
            print('Retriving data from ' + str(link) + '...\n' + str(name) + ':' + str(price))
            f.write('\n' + str(link) + '\n' + str(name) + '\n' + str(price) + '\n')

        elif 'https://example2.com' in url:
            name2 = pageSoup.findAll('div', {'class': 'item-title'})[0].string
            price2 = pageSoup.findAll('span', {'class': 'cur-price'})[0].string
            print('Retriving data from ' + str(link) + '...\n' + str(name2) + ':' + str(price2))
            f.write('\n' + str(link) + '\n' + str(name2) + '\n' + str(price2) + '\n')
```

Thank you for taking the time to check this out, any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: You should read up on exception handling.  Looks like one of the pages you're trying to scrape is blocking you, or doesn't have the element you're looking for.

Comment: Ohh, I see the problem, thanks for clarifying that. I was confused! Where in the documentation is it from? I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This improve above response

```py
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import namedtuple
Data = namedtuple('Data', 'link name price')

def parseData(url):
    link = None
    name = None
    price = None

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        if response:
            # responseContent = response.read()
            pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf-8")
            if 'https://example.com' in url:
                try:
                    name = pageSoup.findAll('h3', {'class': 'tb-main-title'})[0].string
                    price = pageSoup.findAll('em', {'class': 'tb-rmb-num'})[0].string
                except IndexError as e:
                    pass
            elif 'https://example2.com' in url:
                breakpoint()
                try:
                    name = pageSoup.findAll('div', {'class': 'item-title'})[0].string
                    price = pageSoup.findAll('span', {'class': 'cur-price'})[0].string
                except IndexError as e:
                    pass
            link = url
            print('Retriving data from ' + str(link) + '...\n' + str(name) + ':' + str(price))
        return Data(link=link, name=name, price=price)


urls = ["https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.google.com"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for url_ in urls:
        data = parseData(url_)
        if data.link and data.name and data.price:
            with open('output.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write('\n' + str(link) + '\n' + str(name) + '\n' + str(price) + '\n')
```

Comment: I did something similar, and it proved to be faster. Thank you again. It is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is an IndexError and I think both issues can be resolved this way:

```py
import urllib.request

def parseData(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen('url') as response:
        if response:
            responseContent = response.read()
            pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(responseContent, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf-8") 
            if 'https://example.com' in url:
                try:
                    name1 = pageSoup.findAll('h3', {'class': 'tb-main-title'})[0].string
                    price1 = pageSoup.findAll('em', {'class': 'tb-rmb-num'})[0].string
                except IndexError as e:
                    pass
                else:
                    link = url
                    print('Retriving data from ' + str(link) + '...\n' + str(name1) + ':' + str(price1))
                    yield (link, name1, price1)
            elif 'https://example2.com' in url:
                try:
                    name2 = pageSoup.findAll('div', {'class': 'item-title'})[0].string
                    price2 = pageSoup.findAll('span', {'class': 'cur-price'})[0].string
                except IndexError as e:
                    pass
                else:
                    print('Retriving data from ' + str(link) + '...\n' + str(name2) + ':' + str(price2))
                    yield (link, name2, price2)






urls = ["list of urls here"]


if __name__ == "main":
    for url_ in urls:
        link, name, price = parseData(url_)
        with open('output.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write('\n' + str(link) + '\n' + str(name) + '\n' + str(price) + '\n')
```

This code add a manager context and some checks that could avoid some errors

Comment: Thank you very easy for understanding and efficient!

Comment: I did another modification this way